How to delete zoom controll from the Map Container react leaflet. Im using react leaflet library
<MapContainer  center={[coord.lat, coord.lng]} zoom={10}>
<TileLayer
    attribution='&copy;<a href="https//www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap<a/> contributors'
    url="https://api.maptiler.com/maps/outdoor-v2/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=7h6rpJcY0Ib55GV7vQkR"

/>
//I need this zoom control but i have another in the map container and i need to delete it
<ZoomControl/>
<RecenterAutomatically lat={coord.lat} lng={coord.lng} />

enter image description here
here i have 2 of them

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can set the zoomControl attribute of the <MapContainer> component to false to remove the default zoom control and define your own:
<MapContainer center={[52.4498, -1.6]} zoom={10} zoomControl={false}>
    ...
    <ZoomControl position="bottomleft" />
</MapContainer>


There's a StackBlitz here that removes the default zoom control and uses the one I added in the JSX instead (which puts it in the bottom left).

Thank you very much bro. That is what I need))))
